# How to deserialize null array to null in c#?

Tags: c#, xml, arrays, serialization, nullable

Here is my class:

```
public class Command
{
   [XmlArray(IsNullable = true)]
   public List<Parameter> To { get; set; }
}
```

When I serialize an object of this class:

```
var s = new XmlSerializer(typeof(Command));
s.Serialize(Console.Out, new Command());
```

it prints as expected (xml header and default MS namespaces are omitted):

```
<Command><To xsi:nil="true" /></Command>
```

When I took this xml and tried to deserialize it I got stucked, because it always print "Not null":

```
var t = s.Deserialize(...);
if (t.To == null)
    Console.WriteLine("Null");
else
    Console.WriteLine("Not null");
```

How to force deserializer to make my list null, if it is null in xml?

Comment: Is it really that important for you if you have no list or an empty list?

Comment: Yep. I can workaround this case with some flags of course, but I want to know if there is a good standard solution.

Comment: Avoiding null objects is usually a good thing (less error-prone, no need to check for null all around the code etc.). Using a flag would clearly indicate what exactly that null value represents.

Comment: Yes, but, in fact, checking for null will be replaced by checking flags. Thank you for advices ;)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ugh, annoying isn't it.  You can see it being doing by running sgen.exe on your assembly with the /keep and /debug options so you can debug the deserialization code.  It looks roughly like this:

```
global::Command o;
o = new global::Command();
if ((object)(o.@To) == null) o.@To = new global::System.Collections.Generic.List<global::Parameter>();
global::System.Collections.Generic.List<global::Parameter> a_0 = (global::System.Collections.Generic.List<global::Parameter>)o.@To;
// code elided
//...
while (Reader.NodeType != System.Xml.XmlNodeType.EndElement && Reader.NodeType != System.Xml.XmlNodeType.None) {
  if (Reader.NodeType == System.Xml.XmlNodeType.Element) {
    if (((object)Reader.LocalName == (object)id4_To && (object)Reader.NamespaceURI == (object)id2_Item)) {
      if (!ReadNull()) {
        if ((object)(o.@To) == null) o.@To = new global::System.Collections.Generic.List<global::Parameter>();
        global::System.Collections.Generic.List<global::Parameter> a_0_0 = (global::System.Collections.Generic.List<global::Parameter>)o.@To;
        // code elided
        //...
      }
      else {
        // Problem here:
        if ((object)(o.@To) == null) o.@To = new global::System.Collections.Generic.List<global::Parameter>();
        global::System.Collections.Generic.List<global::Parameter> a_0_0 = (global::System.Collections.Generic.List<global::Parameter>)o.@To;
      }
    }
  }
  Reader.MoveToContent();
  CheckReaderCount(ref whileIterations1, ref readerCount1);
}
ReadEndElement();
return o;
```

No less than 3 places where it makes sure the @To property isn't null.  The first one is somewhat defensible, hard to deserialize data when the structure doesn't exist.  The second one does the null test *again*, that's the only real good one.  The third one is the problem, ReadNull() returned true but it *still* creates a non-null property value.

If you want to differentiate between empty and null then you have no good solution but edit this code by hand.  Do this *only* if you are really desperate and the class is 100% stable.  Well, don't do it.  João's solution is the only good one.

Answer (score 5):

If you use an array instead of a list it works as expected

```
public class Command
{
    [XmlArray(IsNullable = true)]
    public Parameter[] To { get; set; }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I agree with @Oliver's comment, but you can solve it like this if you absolutely need it to return null. Instead of using an automatic property, create your own backing field.

```
List<Parameter> _to;
public List<Parameter> To
{
    get
    {
        if (_to != null && _to.Count == 0) return null;
        return _to;
    }
    set { _to = value; }
}
```

Comment: I believe that OP wanted to *differentiate* null and empty lists.

Comment: Unfortunately, in my case, empty list and null list are different.

Answer (score 0):

If you really need that a collection is deserialized to `null` when no values are provided you can do it by not providing a `set` accessor, like this:

```
public class Command
{
    private List<Parameter> to;

    public List<Parameter> To { get { return this.to; } }
}
```

Comment: Bad choice. "To" will be always null after deserialization.

Answer (score 0):

For those who need it you can define the type as array with original element name and then wrap it, this will get you nullable list.

```
[XmlArray(ElementName = nameof(Metadata), IsNullable = true)]
public string[] MetadataArray { get; set; }

[XmlIgnore]
public List<string> Metadata
{
    get => this.MetadataArray?.ToList();
    set => this.MetadataArray = value?.ToArray();
}
```